# PWA setup with magento2.3

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I want to setup PWA with magento 2.3, I have followed magento [documentation](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/),

after that I got pwaDevserver frontend url https://magento-venia.local.pwadev:8001 but it can't be reached. Please see attached screenshot 
[image]

I don't know how to move further, please let me know the further steps.

Comment: please run "`sudo npm run watch:venia`" command after successfully setup

Comment: I did that but still the same issue, not able tio access the PWA Publically.

Comment: did you resolve it? if yes, can you please update the resolution.